# How to permenantly disable (not uninstall) Network Manager on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager

hi I need to disable it in such a way that it does not start on reboot. I did the "Using Systemd" method described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#Stopping_and_Disabling_NetworkManager) but it starts on reboot. Please help... Also please tell how to re-enable it..

Comment: Do you really need to disable it? If you want to manually manage your network interfaces, you can do that without disabling it altogether.

Comment: Yes I know the manual way. Want to disable to try something :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

To permenantly disable Network Manager:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
mv /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service NetworkManager.service.res
```

To renable Network Manager:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
mv /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service.res  NetworkManager.service
systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm about to do this but a doubt. The directory `/lib/systemd/system` has a `NetworkManager.service` and a `network-manager.service` . What is the difference between the two?

Comment: hi this doesn't work (still starts on boot) and moreover now I can't recover my NetworkManager.service file :( :( . It is gone! .  Please help me.

Comment: the `mv` command in my system (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) deletes the file if the destination location does not exist. Why is it so, I did not change it. Can anyone please give a copy of the contents of `/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service` ?

Comment: oh just found it now. I should have known it haha. It moves to current user's home folder because you specified only file name and my terminal was on home folder (default). Please change 2nd step of re-enabling to `mv NetworkManager.service.res  /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service` and add a note to not delete that file from home folder after disabling steps. Network manager still starts on boot though